# Setting background on IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms

With Master-Detail template.
I set the colors on app.xaml
Works fine on Android. But no matter what I do keeps an white background on iOs.

Android:
https://prnt.sc/p19j24

iOs:
https://prnt.sc/p19pse

Tryed setting the background on xaml of the individual page.

Tryed setting background on code behind.

app.xaml

```xml
            <Color x:Key="NavigationPrimary">#007DC6</Color>
            <Color x:Key="NavigationBackground">#E4EBF1</Color>
            <Color x:Key="NavigationBackgroundShadow">#D8E1E6</Color>
            <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
                <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
                <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationBackground}" />
            </Style>
```

about.xaml - frame

```xml
                <Frame BackgroundColor="{StaticResource NavigationBackgroundShadow}"
                       CornerRadius="10"
                       Margin="0,5"
                       x:Name="FrmDistribuidora"
                       IsClippedToBounds="True"
                       Padding="5"
                       HeightRequest="60"
                       BorderColor="#999999">
                    <Label Text="Test" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                </Frame>
```

To reproduce the code...

• Make a new xamarin project with android and IOS and Master-Detail template.

• Paste the app.xaml resources.

• Paste the frame code on about.xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Page's background Color, and it will work on iOS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             BackgroundColor="Yellow"
             x:Class="aaTest.Views.AboutPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:aaTest.ViewModels"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
```

Comment: truly works. even placing
            <Style TargetType="ContentPage">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationBackground}" />
            </Style> 
on app.xaml doesn't work... why would work with android only? xamarin keeps making me disappointed